# how to know which text field is updating by user in php

Tags: php, mysql

Actually I am doing a matrimony website in php I have around 50+ input fields in profile page, i would like to show notifications to website admin when user update anything from his profile page

Example:
If a user update his contact number from his profile page, I have to show admin that particular user is updated contact number

Actually i am running update query for all 50 field each time when user updated his profile

But I am getting confusing how can I know that user is going to update particular field ?

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to ***research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself*** before posting. If you get stuck on something *specific*, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an `audit` table and a trigger, which should get triggered for any/specific table update.

So, when user make any change to their profile, table will be updated, which will trigger and insert new row.

Other, possible solution would be application level, where you execute insert statement just after any update.